# Is it Yii or is it me who is wrong?

Tags: php, yii

Hi there I have written a code that ietrates through whole array and copies the images to a folder and inserts data in record. Now funny thing is that `$model->save()`does not show error it returns true. and program never goes into else

now what happens loop continues to run and completes its ietration without breaking. I can not guess who is wrong. greater chances are me as i am most of time :)

here is code

```
   protected function saveImage($formData,$model)
        {                   
               if ($formData === null)
                   return;                   
                $idx=0;

            foreach($formData['title'] as $image)
            {
                $model->title = $image;                    
                $file= dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
                        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'images\hotelImages'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
                        . $model->hotel->name;

                $model->image = Yii::app()->baseUrl. "/images/hotelImages/".$_FILES['HotelImages']['name'][$idx];//image path

                if($model->save())
                { 
                    echo $idx.'<br /> it was sucess<br />';

                    If(file_exists($file)) 
                    {
                        copy($_FILES['HotelImages']['tmp_name'][$idx],$file."/".$_FILES['HotelImages']['name'][$idx]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         mkdir($file); 
                        copy($_FILES['HotelImages']['tmp_name'][$idx],$file."/".$_FILES['HotelImages']['name'][$idx]);
                    }
                    $idx++;

                }//if there was error
                 else
                 {
                     print_r($model->getErrors());
                     yii::app()->end();                
                    return FALSE;
                 }
                 echo '<br />end reached <br />';


            }
             yii::app()->end(); 
             return true;
        }
```

var_dump for $formdata is

```
array
(
    'title' => array
    (
        '0' => 'title1'
        '1' => 'title2'
    )
)
```

**No mater what ever the ietration count for foreach loop database gets only single row**

Comment: It is the Title that is wrong.

Comment: It's cute, but it doesn't capture the real question/problem :)

Comment: What's going wrong in your code? `$model->save()` returning true sounds good to me ...

Comment: yeh but there is only one entery in database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `save()` method inserts a record into the database *if it doesn't exist yet, and otherwise updates that same database record*.

`$model` is being passed in as a method parameter, and I'm just assuming here that its `title` attribute is not the primary key.

In other words, you keep updating the same database record over and over, which is why you only see one record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

@fivedigit's analysis is correct. My suggested fix would be to reduce the complexity of this method. Put everything inside the `foreach` in its own method (e.g. `saveImage`), then do something like:

```
foreach($formData['title'] as $image) {
  $this->saveImage($image, new Image);
}
```

This method is a bit of a super-method, and you might find it easier to break it out into different methods. Perhaps use a component to handle the file copying, instead of filling up the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**And once again I am wrong** :)

Issue was that in each `foreach ietration` the $`model` was previous and New instant of $model was not created and `yii` thought that hey its old one probably this Geek is updating it. so that is it.it updates in database.

just did 
`$model = new HotelImages;`

before populating them

I thank [fivedigit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920371/fivedigit) for Just an idea.

I have a strong believe on this

---

> Most people says Little knowledge is dangerous...well that is true for
>   all except for programmers. Programmers are rare species and what it all takes is
>   a little idea/hint to do the thing

Answer (score 0):

Yii CActiveRecord has a variable isNewRecord, its value is true when an object is created and remains true until a find or save function is not called. When a model calls save function, isNewRecord set to false.

So in your case you need to set this variable "isNewRecord" true each time before save function called or create a new model each time than call the save function.

See the changes in your code::

```
$model->setIsNewRecord(True); // changes code line

   protected function saveImage($formData,$model)
    {                   
           if ($formData === null)
               return;                   
            $idx=0;

        foreach($formData['title'] as $image)
        {
            $model->setIsNewRecord(True); // for each new record
            $model->title = $image;                    
            $file= dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
                    . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'images\hotelImages'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 
                    . $model->hotel->name;

            $model->image = Yii::app()->baseUrl. "/images/hotelImages/".$_FILES['HotelImages']['name'][$idx];//image path

            if($model->save())
            { 
                echo $idx.'<br /> it was sucess<br />';

                If(file_exists($file)) 
                {
                    copy($_FILES['HotelImages']['tmp_name'][$idx],$file."/".$_FILES['HotelImages']['name'][$idx]);
                }
                else
                {
                     mkdir($file); 
                    copy($_FILES['HotelImages']['tmp_name'][$idx],$file."/".$_FILES['HotelImages']['name'][$idx]);
                }
                $idx++;

            }//if there was error
             else
             {
                 print_r($model->getErrors());
                 yii::app()->end();                
                return FALSE;
             }
             echo '<br />end reached <br />';


        }
         yii::app()->end(); 
         return true;
    }
```